# Symfony2: jQuery plugins working in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig, assetic

TL;DR - jQuery plugins are working in Firefox but not in Chrome. Same page, same files, same everything.

So I've got this twig page that extends another one. In the parent page jquery is being called through assetic like so

```
#FooBar/Resources/view/Default/base.html.twig
{% stylesheets output = 'bundles/foobar/*.js' %}
    '@FooBarBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.js'
{% endstylesheets %}

{% block custom_js %}{% endblock %}
```

Then in a child template I have the following

```
#WooHooBundle/Resources/views/FrontPage/frontpage.html.twig
{% extends 'FooBarBundle:Default:base.html.twig %}
{% block custom_js %}

    {% javascripts  output='bundles/woohoo/js/*.js'   */ (adding this made output look funny)
        '@WooHoBundle/Resources/public/js/Global/guidedTour.js'
        '@WooHoBundle/Resources/public/js/Global/jquery.joyride-2.1.js'
        '@WooHoBundle/Resources/public/js/Global/jquery.cookie.js'
        '@WooHoBundle/Resources/public/js/Global/jquery.number.min.js'
    %}

        <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>

    {% endjavascripts %}

{% endblock %}
```

So when I try to use jquery.number for example in firefox it looks like this (in the console)

```
$.number(1337)
'1337'
```

And in chrome it looks like this

```
$.number(1337)
TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new b.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method 'number'
```

I've looked in the DOM and the plugins are AFTER jquery in the DOM. When I look in resources the plugins appear before jquery. It appears to be alphabetical though and assetic assigns those random values to the beginning of the files on assets:install / assetic:dump. So they look like this

```
10ec069_jquery.number.min_4.js
c2a2536_jquery-1.8.3_1.js
```

So I have no idea why this would be working in firefox and not in chrome.... I have other JS that is being called AFTER the jquery plugins... I've run them throu jsLint and everything is fine there.

Thanks for any help / advice you can give :)

Drew

EDIT:

So I had the [Javascript Library for Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hoooohdeiheekoemicbaeeiaokjhnpko) Extension installed and it was reloading jquery AFTER everything else. disabled it and everything is working fine now

Comment: Turns out I had a chrome extension that was injecting javascript after everything had loaded. Was causing everything to break.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify a file name instead of *.js or a directory.

```
{% javascripts output='javascript.js'
    '@WooHoBundle/Resources/public/js/Global/guidedTour.js'
    '@WooHoBundle/Resources/public/js/Global/jquery.joyride-2.1.js'
    '@WooHoBundle/Resources/public/js/Global/jquery.cookie.js'
    '@WooHoBundle/Resources/public/js/Global/jquery.number.min.js'
%}
```

In production all your JS files should go into 1 file (javascript.js or another name). In Development assetic should put them in several files.

Don't forget to post your symfony version when you have a question.